# How to customise Google+ Log In button

Tags: ios, button, google-plus

I'm including FB and G+ SignUp in my app.

Only thing that I can't find an answer for is **how to customise GPPSignInButton**.

I made a regular UIButton and changed it's Class to GPPSignInButton.

Result was this:

[image]

I have no idea what this blue area is, and how it ended up there, but I cannot change it by calling any of these methods

```
_gButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[_gButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[_gButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I just need a google login button to be transparent button. 
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your own `UIButton`, connect it with an `IBAction` to your `UIViewController` and run the authentication process yourself, that's what the Sign in button does behind the scenes:

```
- (IBAction)signInWithGooglePlusButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    GPPSignIn *googleSignIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    googleSignIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    googleSignIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    googleSignIn.clientID = @"CLIENT_ID";
    googleSignIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];
    googleSignIn.delegate = self;

    [googleSignIn authenticate];
}
```

Comment: Damn.
That's exactly what I was doing and I was wondering why wasn't I successful...
Now I see that I forgot the last method :)
Thanks Gorka!

Comment: @Gorka really great work. It seems working new api.Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and I solved it in this way: I created gppSignInButton but didn't add it as a subview, then created my own button, made it's view exactly like I needed and then added action loginViaGP to my own button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _gppSignInButton = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)loginViaGP:(id)sender
{
    [_gppSignInButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

so after clicking my button G+ dialog was called

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in the `viewDidLoad` and it worked like a charm.

```
[self.googlePlusBtn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.googlePlusBtn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.googlePlusBtn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```